# How to retrieve book related to a specific tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 tables (`User, Tags, Book`).

In the `User` table I have an attribute `Interesting`, it has a tag_id (I saving inside it a tagid). I also have a `Tags` table that has many tags with many to many to book table relation.

```
public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the book table :

```
public partial class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Book_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="User Name")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string User_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the user table :

```
public partial class AspNetUser
{      
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Interesting")]
    public int Interesting { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

What is the SQL statement here to retrieve the book that match the `Interesting` attribute?

For example in Interesting attribute I have 17 , so I want to retrieve the book that related to the tag id 17 ..

Note: my many-to-many table generated from the relation name is `TagBooks`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why Interesting  isn't an int type though it receive a tag_id ?

Comment: it's ok , suppose it int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you all the posts where it is associated with the "Swift" tag.

```
var books = dbContext.Books.Where(s => s.Tags.Any(f => f.Name == "Swift")).ToList();
```

If you want to get the result based on the `TagId`, change the condition in the predicate.

```
var books = dbContext.Books.Where(s => s.Tags.Any(f => f.Id== 17)).ToList();
```